# An interesting identity regarding partitions of $m$ into powers of two

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This question appeared in an exam I was giving-

> Suppose we have $n$ balls and we place them in a sequence of bins as
> follows. At least one ball is put into the first bin, and each
> successive bin has at least as many balls as **all the previous bins
> combined**. This process is continued until all the balls have been
> placed into bins.
>
> Prove that the number of ways of doing this is the same as the number
> of partitions of n into powers of 2, not necessarily distinct.
>
> Note: $1=2^0$ is also considered a power of two.

I think this identity is superb. It breaks my brains to even think that the two processes are equivalent. But, that doesn't help me to solve it.

All I can think of is that the tightest case of putting balls into bins is $1,1,2,4,8,\dots$ which is the sequence of powers of two. Also, I know that the number of partitions of $m$ into powers of two is the coefficient of $x^m$ in the product
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{2^n j}
\end{equation*}
But, none of these proved useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Let $b_i$ be the number of balls in the $i$th bin for $i=1,\dots, N$ where $N$ is the total number of bins. Let $x_i=b_i-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}b_j$ which is non negative by assumption. Then
$$\begin{cases}
b_1=x_1\\
b_1+b_2=b_1+(b_1+x_2)=2b_1+x_2=2x_1+x_2\\
b_1+b_2+b_3=b_1+b_2+(b_1+b_2+x_3)=2(b_1+b_2)+x_3=4x_1+2x_2+x_3\\
\dots
\end{cases}$$
and therefore $b_1+b_2+\dots+b_N=n$ if and only if
$$2^{N-1}x_1+2^{N-2}x_2+\dots+x_N=n \qquad (1).$$
So the number of ways of doing the given process is equal to the number of nonnegative integer solutions of equation (1).

Comment: Shouldn't equation (1) start with $2^{n-1}x_1$ instead of $2^nx_1$?

Comment: @SayanDutta Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Otherwise, the solution was really interesting.

Comment: @SayanDutta Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show in both cases that if $a_n$ is the number of such partitions:

- $a_0=1$
- $a_{2k}=a_{2k-2}+a_k$
- $a_{2k+1}=a_{2k}$

For the second equation

- in your first case, either take a partition of $2k-2$ and add $2$ to the largest existing bin, or take a partition of $k$ and add a new bin with $k$.
- in your second case, either take a partition of $2k-2$ and add two $1$ parts, or take a partition of $k$ and double each part

For the third equation

- in your first case, take a partition of $2k$ and add $1$ to the largest existing bin
- in your second case, take a partition of $2k$ and add one $1$ part